# Is there a risk in changing the C++ dialect to C++11, but keeping the standard library non C++11 on XCode4?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, c++11, clang

Let's say I have a cross platform (Win & Mac) production code base that does not use any C++11.

Let's say that the compiler options on mac have been changed to use the C++11 language dialect, but without the C++11 standard library.

I have tried googling around to understand the possible implications, but am coming up empty.

My questions are:

1. What does changing the language dialect in clang even mean?
2. What is the risk with doing something like this?

Comment: C++11 is not a "language dialect". It is a new version of the language. "Dialect" implies some sense of cross-compatibility.

Comment: I only used the words dialect, because in order to get C++11 code to compile on XCode4, you need to set both the "Language Dialect" and "Standard Library" build options to C++11. I get your point though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't use XCode, but I imagine if they're shipping a (presumably incomplete but getting there) C++11 mode for clang, then they're also shipping a (presumably incomplete but getting there) C++11 standard library. And testing them together. So your situation *shouldn't* arise, but assuming it has anyway:

1. Formally it doesn't mean anything, because the standard doesn't recognize any way of mixing and matching "language" and "libraries". It's up to your compiler what it thinks it means. Probably what it means is that new "language features" like rvalue references, lambdas, etc, become available, but new classes and functions in namespace `std` don't.
2. Main risk is probably that you're no longer programming to a recognized standard, you're programming to a possibly under-documented thing invented by your compiler. If the compiler says that in C++11 mode it needs a C++11 standard library, and you supply it with a C++03 standard library, then you don't even have the compiler docs to blame -- anything might happen, you broke it, your fault.

Quite aside from the risk of this funny combination, there are small risks in taking a C++03 code base and compiling it using *any* C++11 compiler. There are some code constructs in C++03 that compile as C++11 but with subtly (or grossly) different meaning.

For example it is just about possible to write a class in C++03 that will break when used in C++11, because C++11 will generate a move constructor that doesn't do the right thing. Sometimes you have to replace a compiler-generated copy constructor that doesn't do the right thing (Rule of Three), and while C++11 ensures that in those "normal" situations the move constructor is suppressed, there are some odd edge cases. Unfortunately I can't remember them at the moment.

The C++11 standard lists some incompatibilities between C++11 and C++03. You'd hope all, but you know how it is. The list is in appendix C. It starts with:

> Valid C++ 2003 code may fail to compile or produce different results
>   in this International Standard. Specifically, macros named `R`, `u8`, `u8R`,
>   `u`, `uR`, `U`, `UR`, or `LR` will not be expanded when adjacent to a string
>   literal but will be interpreted as part of the string literal.

and it doesn't get much more riveting reading from there. But it's basically a list of things that, if they appear in your C++03 code base, need changing in order to get equivalent C++11.

Comment: Not to mention the fact that those C++03 constructs that don't work in C++11 may well appear in the C++03 *standard library*.

Comment: @NicolBolas: very good point. All the same issues apply to the library implementation as to the questioner's code base.

Comment: Thanks. I also found the list of differences between C++11 and C++03 in the standard - Appendix C, here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3376.pdf

Answer (score 1):

There's not really 'risk' but a lot of the value from C++11 comes from the library.

Changing the language to C++11 means that C++11 language features are supported. If you look at the standard you'll see that it's divided into language (clauses 1-16) and library (clauses 17-30) features. Language features cover things like grammar, meanings of expressions and statements, overload resolution, etc. Library features cover the content of standard headers. So if you need a particular header to do something in C++11 then you probably need a C++11 standard library.

Xcode supports a version of libstdc++ that shipped with gcc 4.2 and was built for C++03. This works fine when clang is set to C++11 mode. It also supports libc++, which is designed to provide many C++11 features even with a C++03 compiler. So mixing and matching should work fine for the most part. However you'll get much more value by using the language and library that were designed for each other together.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that many C++11 language features are backed by library features- for example, you won't have much use for rvalue references without `std::move` and `std::forward`, and initializer lists will be junk too.

Answer (score 0):

GCC and clang compile c++ slightly differently. this may make no difference in your case, but in someone else's it might, so you can switch back to GNU-style compilation. Hence "language dialect".

As long as you keep the language and stdlib set to GNU versions, it shouldn't make a difference. But compiling with Apple LLVM compiler (clang) in GNU dialects may not produce the same results as on windows (assuming you use GCC on both). I'd say you are always at some risk unless you use matching libs, compilers, and settings on both platforms, especially when 3rd-party libraries come into play and you swap out libstdc++ with libc++ for C++11 support.

in case you use VC++ on windows, it's C++11 support is rather lacking, so don't be surprised when your XCode code refuses to build in VC++.